# org-mode babel german

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to export an org file to PDF via LaTeX but in German.
I set `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` but when exporting org-mode adds `english` to the babel options.

That causes all the automatic titles,i.e. references, table of contents, etc., to be in English.

Is there a way to prevent the setting of the *english* option in babel?

Comment: Either use `#+language: de` keyword locally or the `org-export-default-language` variable globally.